# Why is EXEC required to execute procedures?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

Why is `EXEC` or `EXECUTE` required when calling a stored procedure?  Both Oracle and SQL Server have cases when `EXEC` is required and when it's not required or necessary.  What's the point of ever requiring it?

Comment: The [documentation for EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189915%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in SQL Server says: "To execute a stored procedure, use the Transact-SQL EXECUTE statement. Alternatively, you can execute a stored procedure without using the EXECUTE keyword **if the stored procedure is the first statement in the batch."**

Comment: It's required because, if you don't provide it, the SQL interpreter can't figure out what you're trying to do.  How do you distinguish it from a SELECT or an UPDATE, for example?  SQL Server makes an exception if the stored procedure is the first statement in the batch (presumably, it checks the stored procedures to see if it exists).

Comment: To put it another way, your question is basically the same as "Why is SELECT required when querying a table?  Why doesn't the database just assume I'm doing a SELECT?  After all, SELECT is probably the most common operation performed on a SQL database, so why not make it the default operation?"

Comment: Why is it OK to omit `EXEC` on the first line?  If the interpreter can distinguish it from a SELECT then, what's stopping it later?

Comment: The parser state is different at the beginning of a batch. For instance, you can also do an `INSERT #tbl EXEC storedproc @a, @b` go get the resultset of a SP into a table. Let me tell you, the (old) T-SQL remains are already ambiguous enough as they stand. The more strict a language is, the easier it is to make an efficient parser for it. Many (albeit not all) keywords which can come as first item in a T-SQL statement always indicate the start of a new statement (unless they are nested in a subquery, which is easily handled tough). The parser has less "guesswork" to do that way.

Comment: (ctd.) Compared to compiled languages it is important to keep in mind that T-SQL ist often executed on the fly (dynamic SQL, generated by ORMs), so that the parser performance is much more important than in languages like C#, Java or VB where the performance of the parser is less critical. Note that even when query plans are cached and re-used, the parsing will still have to be performed.

Comment: @Lucero Thanks for your comments.  Even while others are clicking the "close" on my question I found your responses very informative!

Comment: @Alex, you're welcome. I've done my share of T-SQL and PL/SQL, in fact I even wrote a full parser for T-SQL so this question was a must-answer for me. Still, I also clicked "close", because the question per se is not a good fit for a Q&A format; the "why" probably cannot be answered conclusively.

Comment: @Lucero Maybe I didn't phrase my question very well and should have asked if it's possible to develop a TSQL or PLSQL parser without requiring the EXEC keyword.  Still, my bad question generated a healthy discussion and interesting information, so I'm happy about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes the syntax more distinct and unambiguous. Since statement separators (semicolons) are not mandatory in T-SQL, it makes it clearer to find where statements begin.

On a sidenote, I recomment to strictly use semicolons after each statement because there are ambiguity problems (especially often encountered when using the `WITH` keyword, which can either start the definitions of common table expressions before DML statements, or be used at the end of DML statement for defining hints; without a semicolon, the parser cannot know which one to pick really).

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, even though it was your total contribution spread across this question's comments and [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21846/discussion-between-dcookie-and-lucero) that paints a more complete picture

Answer (score 3):

It's undoubtedly a parser problem/challenge. If a call to a stored proc can be anywhere in a body of text, you'll kill yourself trying to write a universal "thing" that can understand it all. Instead, the designers publish the [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) for the language and you, the user, are responsible for understanding how to speak it.

Or, in the SQL Server world always use EXEC/EXECUTE and never have to worry about the finer points of when it is needed. As noted by @alex, that doesn't hold true for Oracle.

Comment: always using EXEC for T-SQL may work, but not for PL/SQL, where you'll get an error if `EXEC` is present

Comment: Thank you for the education @Alex, updated the answer to reflect that axiom is only for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, EXECUTE (or EXEC) is used in SQL*Plus as a shortcut for an anonymous PL/SQL block. EXECUTE will not work in PL/SQL.  You could do either:

```
SQL> execute my_proc;
```

Or, as a fully specified anonymous block:

```
SQL> DECLARE
BEGIN
  my_proc;
END;
/
```

It's entirely client syntax in Oracle.

Comment: Why can't Oracle attempt to find a stored procedure with a matching name instead of failing on the SQL prompt when `EXEC` is missing?

Comment: I don't know. The simple answer is because that's the way they built SQL*Plus.

Comment: No the answer is because PL/SQL is like two interweaved languages which can alternate. That's also why some things are just "different" in SQL statements embedded in PL/SQL compared to what you can do in the PL code parts; there are differences regarding variables, operators and other things. So in SQL*Plus it doesn't expect PL but SQL, and by creating a PL/SQL block you basically switch languages.

Comment: See also the [Oracle PL/SQL FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/PL/SQL_FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_SQL_and_PL.2FSQL.3F).

Comment: No, PL/SQL is PL/SQL, not two interweaved languages. SQL*Plus is a client which submits SQL queries and PL/SQL programs/blocks to the database engine. The EXEC construct helps SQL*Plus interpret the request as an anonymous PL/SQL block, rather than a single query.

Comment: SQL and PL/SQL are two languages. While a SQL DML subset is supported natively in PL/SQL, it has for instance no support whatsoever for DDL (e.g. `CREATE TABLE` etc.), to do anything like that in PL/SQL you have to revert to dynamic SQL that is executed using an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command. It's not like T-SQL on SQL Server where there is ONE language dealing with everything the server does; you have multiple languages on Oracle (and, besides PL/SQL, you can use Java and even .NET on Windows systems for SPs and the like).

Comment: (ctd.) That, and the fact that Oracle doesn't handle DML in a transaction context, makes it very difficult to write "smart" migration scripts which don't leave a mess if they fail for whatever reason (e.g. doing a full rollback of all DML and DDL performed in the migration is basically impossible).

Comment: I would argue T-SQL and SQL are two different languages as well. There are many elements to T-SQL that are not found in the SQL standard.

Comment: @DCookie, you're completely missing the point. In Orcacle there is plain SQL (only DDL and DML), and there is PL/SQL (procedural, loops, variables, and some DML). Both cover their area, but neither can do everything that Oracle does. With T-SQL that's a completely different story; you have one language that does everything on the SQL Server platform, you can use variables everywhere, invoke DDL everywhere, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21846/discussion-between-dcookie-and-lucero)